# Function for prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im having a problem with an excercise in python.
I should get a function is_prime(n): to define prime numbers.
the program should give 3 types of output;
1. n is the multiplicative identity
2. n is not a prime number (n * d = n).
3. n is a prime.

im having a problem to get the 2. work right 
my output is: 
 12 is not a prime number.(2, '*', 6, '=', 12)

but should be

12 is not a prime number (2 * 6 = 12).

my code;

```
def is_prime(n):
    msg1 = "is the multiplicative identity."
    msg2 = "is not a prime number."
    msg3 = "is a prime."
    if n == 1:
        return str(n) + msg1

    for d in range(2, n):
        msg4 = (d, "*", n // d, "=", n)
        pass
        if (n % d) == 0:
         return str(n) + " " + msg2 + str(msg4)

else:
    return str(n) + " " + msg3

print(is_prime(12))
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate till ```n```. It's enough to do it till ```n//2``` to tell whether it's prime, or not

Comment: Actually, it's enough to do until `sqrt(n)`. Why? Because (unless `n` is a perfect square), all integer factors will have one less than the square root and one greater than the square root. So checking anything above the square root will essentially be looking for factors you've already looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) to return instead of concatenation.

This is using `f string` formatting:

```py
return f'{n} {msg2} {msg4}'
```

Anything inside the brackets `{}` is going to be evaluated like standard Python should be or will return that value. It will be converted to a string on it's own so you don't need to `str()` on it.

All code:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    msg1 = "is the multiplicative identity."
    msg2 = "is not a prime number"
    msg3 = "is a prime."
    if n == 1:
        return f'{n} {msg1}'
    for d in range(2, n):
        msg4 = f'({d} * {n // d} = {n})'
        if (n % d) == 0:
            return f'{n} {msg2} {msg4}.'
    return f'{n} {msg3}'

print(is_prime(12))
```

Comment: thank you for that tip, but the output is still; 12 is not a prime number (2, '*', 6, '=', 12). it should be 12 is not a prime number (2 * 6 = 12).

Comment: @Aru I fixed it. I missed the `msg4` in there.

Comment: This will not work for odd composite numbers. It will always return once it checks for ````d=2````

Comment: @NebiyouTen Their question was on how to get the proper returns in a good string format. Whether their code actually returns the appropriate prime numbers or not is outside the scope of what they asked about. If you have a correction for that you can suggest it though and I'll be happy to add it in for future readers.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb correct, but for a complete solution, it might be better to do a minor edit. I have made a minor edit, if you agree, you can approve it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code as you need to use str() function in order to print the expected result.

```
msg4 = str(d) + '*' + str(n // d) +'='+ str(n)
```

If you want to use () then below is the whole code.

```
def is_prime(n):
    msg1 = "is the multiplicative identity."
    msg2 = "is not a prime number."
    msg3 = "is a prime."
    if n == 1:
        return str(n) + msg1

    for d in range(2, n):
        msg4 = "(" + str(d) + '*' + str(n // d) +'='+ str(n)+ ")"
        pass
        if (n % d) == 0:
            return str(n) + " " + msg2 + str(msg4)

        else:
            return str(n) + " " + msg3
```